# How to get local time zone of own machine using joda DateTime

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I want to get DateTime of own machine not considering the server time it's connected to. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The real question is... "How did you try achieve this?"
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [`DateTimeZone.getDefault()`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getDefault--)

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
    System.out.println(zone);
```

On my computer I got

> Europe/Copenhagen

This agrees with the computer’s time zone setting.

What it really gives me is the time zone setting of the JVM. This may not always agree with the computer’s setting since the JVM may have been launched with a different setting on the command line and/or its setting may have been changed later from within your program or another program running in the same JVM.